# How to configure an alternate remote desktop public port for an Azure Resource Manager virtual machine

Tags: azure

I am trying to configure an alternate remote desktop port (other than the default 3389) for an Azure Resource Manager Virtual Machine (the new kind, not the legacy Classic one).

I know how to do it for the Classic kind (via Endpoints), but I can not find an option like that for the new Resource Manager one.

The furthest I got was discovering that I can manipulate the rules for the Network Security Group associated to the VM, but I don't see an option there to map a specific public port to the 3389 private port for that given VM.

Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think below sample template is what you are looking for

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-with-rdp-port

Quote from above sample

```
"rdpPort": {
  "type": "int",
  "defaultValue": 50001,
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Public port number for RDP"
  }
}
```

Comment: The key trick is, to quote the readme of that template sample, "load balancer with a NAT rule for RDP"